# NEAR protocol ¿How can i transfer a NFT's copy?

Tags: nearprotocol

im working minting NFT with n copies with the NEP-171 and i wanna know how can i tranfer a copy.
I see paras.id use something like

```
'{"token_id":"1:1","receiver_id":"comic1.test.near"}'
```

refering to the token and the copy number.

Does anyone know how to transfer a single copy of the NFT?

Comment: I don't understand why this question gets down votes. I think it's a good question, and helps clarify what copies of NFTs actually are, and how to use them

Answer (score 0):

In order to transfer an NFT token implemented using the [NEP-171](https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/Core.html) standard, you can call the `nft_transfer` function on the contract. The function signature looks like this:

```ts
function nft_transfer(
  receiver_id: string,
  token_id: string,
  approval_id: number|null,
  memo: string|null,
) {}
```

the function will transfer only one token, not all copies. Only the [TokenMetadata](https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/Metadata.html) holds information about the number of copies. The token token itself is not all copies, just one of them. Each token in the collection will have a different id.

Then you can call it like this using the [near-cli](https://github.com/near/near-cli):

```
near call contractName nft_transfer '{"token_id":"someTokenId","receiver_id":"comic1.test.near"}' --accountId yourAccoutnId
```

**EDIT**

After looking at your own answer, I think maybe you have misunderstood what the "copies" field mean.

Let's look at the following call in your question

```
'{"token_id":"1:1","receiver_id":"comic1.test.near"}'
```

Here, I assume that this is the first edition of your token that you want to transfer. If you have 10 copies, you should have 9 more tokens, where the id is different. Most likely, they will have the following format on the token_id: `"token_id":"sameIdForAllTokens:edition"`, where `sameIdForAllTokens` is the common ID amongst NFTs in your collection (in your example, it's 1). `edition` is a number that varies, e.g. from 1 to 10 (if you have 10 copies). Now, all of this depends on how the contract is implementented, but this is the format I've seen on paras.id.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement what john says,but in fact
when i use the nft_tranfer send the token and also the copies,not one copy how he says.

this is the original metadata info.

> {
> token_id: '2',
> owner_id: 'dokxo.testnet',
> metadata: {
> title: 'Thunder Sword',
> description: 'Thunder Sword 2',
> media: '',
> copies: 10,
> extra: "{'burrito_type':'Planta','hp':'5','attack':'6','defense':'7','speed':'8','win':'0','level':'1'}",},}

and then we make the transfer with:

```
near call dev-1643782582362-23960957659801 nft_transfer '{"token_id":"2","receiver_id":"dokxotest.testnet"}' --accountId dokxo.testnet --deposit 0.000000000000000000000001
```

so this is new metadata:

> {
> token_id: '2',
> owner_id: 'yairnava.testnet',
> metadata: {
> title: 'Thunder Sword',
> description: 'Thunder Sword 2',
> media: '',
> copies: 10,
> extra: "{'burrito_type':'Planta','hp':'5','attack':'6','defense':'7','speed':'8','win':'0','level':'1'}",},}

and then when i try to send the same token it returns this cuz i'm not the token's owner anymore:

```
Failure [dev-1643782582362-23960957659801]: Error: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: Unauthorized"}}
```

May I need to implement something else or change the minting method?

Comment: This looks correct. You transferred one (and only one) token from 'dokxo.testnet' to 'yairnava.testnet', not all copies. According to the metadata, you should have 10 copies of this token type in total. The other 9 copies should have the more or less the same data, except for the id. Other fields such as title and owner_id does not have to be the same. I also think you can change stats if you want to depending on the eidition. So where are the other 9 tokens? Did you create them already? I've seen that paras.id uses this format on the id: `token_id:"someId:edition"`.

Comment: I don't know how your minting function looks like, but I have a feeling you are currently not creating 10 copies. I think you create one token, and in the metadata specify that there should be 10.

Comment: This is how my minting funtion looks like :                                                                                                                                                             `self.tokens.mint(token_id.clone(),account.clone(),Some(token_metadata.clone())`   and we just send the copies numbers int the metadata

Comment: ¿May can you share me an example about how to mint multiple token?,im looking at the Near/rust documentation but i cant find anything about it. i'll be grateful.

Comment: I don't have any examples at hand, and couldn't find any. I'll ask around, but for now, I checked what methods paras has available, https://stats.gallery/mainnet/x.paras.near/contract?t=month, and they have one called `nft_create_series`. I believe this function will create the metadata for the series. I'm also guessing they keep track of how many tokens are created, and that the `nft_mint` method will mint a token based on the metadata in the series. I don't know if this helps, but it was all I could find. How to mint multiple tokens is a different question, and may be worth asking too.